# UIAlertController not showing multiline messages

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am working on IOS app, I have been fetching and sending data using Web services. Sometimes I need to show message, like error messages with a detail. So I have been using following message to show Alert to user with a message. and it was perfect

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: ""+title, message: ""+msg, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: ""+txtBtnPositive, style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
    if(shouldExitScreen){
        self.navigationController!.popViewController(animated: true)

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}))

self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This is a code snippet that was working fine. The long message were being shown on multilines if they were long. Single line messages hae no problem.

But Suddenly the UiAlertController is showing long messages in one line with truncated from tail. However i did not made change in the code. I do not know why this is happening. Any hint ?

Comment: just debug your code may be you are calling API two times and message change dynamically. UiAlertController can' behave like that.

Comment: no , even I have using this code , on one button and it says this message to user on click "This feature is not yet available in free version, But will be available soon.Thank you" 
I was showing exactly this message , and I have not change the message and the Ui Alert code and this static message also coming in the single line. I do not know what is the problem ?

Comment: Any chances you set the `UILabel's` `numberOfLines` using proxy when contained in `UIAlertController`

Comment: which UILabel ?

Comment: I also have the same issue, my alertController is truncated. How can make as normal one.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way that UIAlertController behave as you are saying. As its default behavior is to show text in the UiLabel with multi lines and with center alignment.

I doubted that you have used the Extension, as indicated by Kamran in comment. It might be proxy (extention) that may be changing its default behavior.

Take a quick look at your extensions and see if that has any impact on UiLabel. If there is any proxy over UILabel, then it will be the culprit.

Comment: oh I understand that, Yes I did inserted one, after removing that , mu alerts are now good again.

Comment: @Androidteem How did you resolve this issue? Please tell me.

Comment: what is your issue @Hilaj

Comment: My alertController still show the message as truncated. I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: can you send me its screenshot